# Returing tuple giving an error tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, class, properties

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def get_features(self):
        return (1,2,3,)

    def execute(self):
        print self.get_features()

f = Foo()
f.execute()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

What I am interested in is actually the length of that tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be calling properties.  Instead, you access them like normal attributes:

```
def execute(self):
    print self.get_features
```

The only difference between properties and attributes is that properties have getter and setter functions which get called *implicitly* when you access or set their values.  For more information, see the [documentation for `property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Also, your class should be inheriting from `object`:

```
class Foo(object):
```

You should always do this in Python 2.x so that your class becomes a [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class), which has far more functionality than an old-style one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have the @property decorator on your get_features() function, making it a property, hence it isn't callable.

This means that execute() simply has to print the attribute, and not call it as a function